# Sefer Chossen Yehoshua on diligence in Torah study

Tags: sources-mekorot, torah-study, kanievsky

Rav Chaim Kanievsky zt"l, in his [Orchos Yosher](https://tablet.otzar.org/#/book/106397/p/92/t/0.77566886125585691234/fs/iRw7qOe0wCMmpPv392Oz5Xy0CWHWbSM2BmmGmkLUTwb2/start/590/end/592/c) (p.91 and 396 in the [new edition](https://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781422622544.html)) recommends reading Sefer Chossen Yehoshua chapter 1, where the topic of diligence in Torah study is greatly discussed.

> והיתר ע"כ וע בם' חוסן יהושע פ"א שכתב לשום אל לבו כי כובד עבודת השקידח לא יאריכו לו ימים בו ולא ימשוך זמן רב אשר יצטרך לכוף את יצרו בחזקה כי בהרגילו את עצמו לשקוד על תלמודו משך זמן הנה ההרגל וזכות התורה שלמד בצער יפעול בו להחליף מבעו ולאמץ שקידתו יום יום וכמו שארז"ל שהש"ו פ א נמשלה התורה בשמן דכתיב שמן תורק שמך מה שמן זה תחלתו מר וסופו מתוק כך הם ד"ת אדם מצטער בהם בתחלה ועושה בהם אחרית עובה שנא' והי' ראשיתך מצער ואחריתך ישגה מאד וע"ש שהאריך בזה וכדאי מאד ללמוד בספר הזה כי כולו נתייסד על שקידת התורה ע"ש ולפום צערא אגרא וכמה שיקשה לו בתחלה כנגד זה יצליח בסופו רק שיתחזק בתורה בכל כחו ועקשן יצליח

Rav Chaim quotes the following from Sefer Chossen Yehoshua in the new edition of Orchos Yosher:

> Then, though your beginning was insignificant, your end will floruish exceedingly (Chossen Yehoshua, chapter 1)

1. Who is the author of this Chossen Yehoshua, since there are a lot of versions available?
2. Where can this exact quote be found (link to the citation in chapter 1 will do it)
3. What is the overall topic of Chossen Yehoshua that Rav Chaim quotes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The author is [HaRav Yehoshua Heller](https://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/7538-heller-joshua-ben-aaron) who was the Av Beis Din of Telz

The clearest edition is the newer version starting [here](https://tablet.otzar.org/#/book/50515/p/28/t/0.27869405850433251234/fs/BKRixyltg76T5qojVnNdU5TDPT6Xlv3MO1RPzxuscteu/start/0/end/3/c) (by the letter alef and following over the page)

> "אדם מצטער בהם בתחלה ועושה בהם אחרית טובה, שנאמר (איוב ח, ז) "והיה ראשיתך מצער ואחריתך ישגה מאד
>
> A person will be in pain at the beginning, and (yet, if he) does them (i.e. is diligent and learns Torah despite the difficulty), afterwards will be good. As it says ([Iyov 8:7](https://www.sefaria.org/Job.8.7?lang=bi)) "Though your beginning be small, in the end you will grow very great.".

Comment: Thanks Dov! Is the entire sefer dedicated to the topic of diligence in study? Or just this section?

Comment: It would seem that the whole sefer is dedicated to providing a guide for success in Torah study, specifically how to overcome the obstacles that hold us back. The first perek specifically deals with acquiring diligence in learning and how to more readily ingrain this trait into our learning.

Comment: Wonderful. It seems a great sefer that will be full of interesting ideas and advice. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it's a great find! Definitely one for the shopping list!